# Desabilitar cache do IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, iis

Estou tendo problemas com cache do IIS *(creio que o problema seja ele)*, sempre que faço alguma alteração no banco de dados, as alteração não acontece no site, fica com os dados antigos.

As alterações somente aparecem quando eu desligo e ligo o IIS.

## Tentativas

Adicionei esse comando no `web.config`

```
<caching enabled="false" />
```

No controller, também adicionei esse *annotation*

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

E por fim, no `global.asax` adicionei esse método

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Nenhuma dessas tentativas deu certo, talvez o problema não seja cache, não sei...

**Controller**

```
public class CursosController : Controller
{
    private SiteContext db = new SiteContext();

    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult Index(Cursos curso)
    {
        return View(curso);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Leonardo, acredito que desabilitar a `Cache` não seja o melhor caminho, imagino mais algum problema de estrutura do seu projeto.

Comment: Se possível, compartilhe o código de seu `controller`.

Comment: @PabloVargas Adicionei o código do `controller`.

Comment: Tente usar `[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]`

Comment: Por que não buscar os cursos dentro do método `Index`?

Comment: @MarllonNasser Boa pergunta, nem me dei conta que ele passa o Cursos pra Index

Comment: @PabloVargas Não deu certo usando esse código que você mandou.

Comment: Altera a tua Index pra não receber os Cursos e sim buscar no banco antes do retorno, podendo ficar assim `public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    } `

Comment: @MarllonNasser Eu estou passando o `Curso` via `MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler`. Vou mudar e tentar buscar através do `Index`.

Comment: @PabloVargas na verdade na `Index` vou ter que receber um parâmetro via `GET`, pois vou mostrar um único curso. `site.com/curso/administracao`

Comment: obtenha os dados do curso em tempo real... ou seja, antes de ir para a view, busque os dados do banco para o curso que você quer e depois jogue o objeto preenchido do banco para a view.

Comment: Cara, isso aconteceu comigo algumas vezes já. Sempre pensei que fosse algo do além porque nunca vi ninguém reclamar disso. Fico no aguardo de uma resposta e, também, de uma explicação pra isso acontecer.

Comment: Então faça o seguinte na sua index `public ActionResult Index(int id) { return View(db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Id == id)); }`

Comment: @PabloVargas Deu certo, as alterações estão sendo exibidas corretamente. Mudei a lógica e consulta está sendo feita somente no controller.

Comment: @jbueno Consegui resolver o problema do meu somente mudando o lugar aonde está sendo feita a consulta ao banco de dados.

Comment: @Leonardo Não entendi. Tem como exemplificar?

Comment: Acho que a resposta cabe a você mesmo publicar. Explique bem o que fizeste pra corrigir o teu problema

Comment: @PabloVargas Certo. Assim que eu tiver um tempinho eu elaboro uma resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterei meu `Controller` para realizar a consulta do **Curso** no banco de dados, e não receber de outro lugar, ficando dessa forma:

```
public ActionResult Index(string parametro)
{
    var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Slug == parametro);
    if (curso == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return View(curso);
}
```

Note que agora estou recebendo como parâmetro uma `string` e não um `Curso`, diferente de como estava na pergunta. Também não é preciso mais colocar a seguinte `annotation`

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```